# FirebaseUser getMetadata returns null

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to get the creation date of the current firebase user which is currently signed in in my application. So i'm using the code below:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getMetadata().getCreationTimestamp();
```

But `getMetadata()` always returns null.
I am using firebase version **12.0.1**. Do you have any suggestions why this could happen?

Comment: you use old version try to update to the latest version and should be worked, check my answer for more info

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure you use latest version of google-services like below:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Then update all your firebase dependencies to the latest version:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

If you using other firebase libraries check below (based on [this link](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions)):

```
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
```

If you using google services check also be updated like below (based [on this link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
```

For null error logout and login. Then try something like:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    user.getMetadata().getCreationTimestamp();
}
```

Comment: When i update to firebase-core:16.0.1 i get a compile error `class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found` on a strange place? Am i missing something?

Comment: @Thomas Meinhart Yes i forgot to told you update all play-services libraries too, i update my answer. Is this help you?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated every library and got rid of the errors. But `getMetadata()` still returns null.

Comment: As you mentioned in your updated answer, after logout and login again `getMetadata()` returns values again. Is there an option without forcing the user to logout and login again?

Comment: @ThomasMeinhart from your user from now on should be worked fine is the problem with version of dependencies.

Comment: But our application is in production and we have several thousand users. Do all of them need to logout and login again when i release a new version?

Comment: @ThomasMeinhart install your application from playstore in your phone log in with old app and then install this new apk you will see what happend i think there not should be any problem..